# Boolean check inside a for loop in a Django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In a Django template I have the following for loop

```
 {% for document in documents %}
      <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a></li>
 {% endfor %}
```

Through this loop I am showing the user all the uploaded files of my app.

Now say that I want to show the user only the files he/she has uploaded.

I have the current user in the variable `{{ request.user }}`
and also I have the user who did the i-th upload in `{{ document.who_upload }}`

My question is how can I compare these two variables inside the loop to show only the uploads that have a `who_upload` field that of the current user?

For example I tried the syntax

```
{% if {{ request.user }} == {{ document.who_upload }} %}
{% endif %}
```

but it does not seem to work.

What is the proper syntax for this check?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get the job done:

```
{% if request.user.username == document.who_upload.username %}
{% endif %}
```

But you should consider performing this logic in your view. This is assuming you're not looping over the entire queryset anywhere else.

```
views.py
========
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Document

def documents(request):
    queryset = Document.objects.filter(who_upload=request.user)

    return render(request, 'document_list.html', {
        'documents': queryset
    })
```

Comment: The check `{% if request.user == document.who_upload %}
{% endif %}` gives as output an empty list. Double checked also that indeed there is at least one upload by the current authenticated user. Incorporating the logic in the view gives however the correct result. Thank you very much Scott.

Comment: I updated the logic in the conditional to compare usernames which would work too.

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be to compare the users' primary keys, instead of comparing user objects, which most definitely will be different.

```
{% if request.user.pk == document.who_upload.pk %}
    <span>You uploaded this file</span>
{% endif %}
```